# How to bind a textblock visibility to another textblock text property

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

```
<Grid
    Height="{Binding ElementName=oldPrice, Path=Height}">
  <TextBlock
      VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
      FontSize="{StaticResource TextStyleSmallFontSize}"
      RequestedTheme="Light"
      FontWeight="Bold"
      Foreground="#B0B0B0"
      Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"
      TextWrapping="NoWrap">
    <Run
      x:Name="oldPrice"
      Text="{Binding oldPrice}" />
  </TextBlock>
  <Line
      Stretch="Fill"
      Stroke="#B0B0B0"
      StrokeThickness="1"
      X1="1"
      Width="{Binding ElementName=oldPrice, Path=Width}"
      Height="{Binding ElementName=oldPrice, Path=Height}"
      Margin="0,6,0,0" />
</Grid>
<TextBlock
    Text="&#160;&#160;&#160;"
    FontSize="{StaticResource TextStyleMediumFontSize}"
    RequestedTheme="Light"
    Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"
    TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
```

Hi all, i have a textblock and a line above it for oldPrice indication. And another textblock for spacing between next text. However when there is no dicount so no oldPrice value i am setting the oldPrice text to null.

So i want to hide that spacing textblock too. Is there any possible xaml way to bind the last TextBlock's visibility property to oldPrice's text. So it will be invisible if oldPrice text is null or empty string.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Converters You can achieve this

In xaml

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="TB" Text="Text"/>
 <TextBox Visibility="{Binding ElementName=TB,Path=Text,Converter={StaticResource StringToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

And Corresponding converter in c# code is

```
 public class StringToVisibilityConverter: IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value)?Visibility.Collapsed:Visibility.Visible;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

If you Bind Visibility to text directly means,It will Show the text something Like Visible/Hidden always.

Comment: Had to add <local:StringToVisibilityConverter x:Key="StringToVisibilityConverter" /> in xaml to get it recognized. And it worked. Thanks.